# <input type="hidden" name="_type" value="on"> generated with <input type="checkbox"> on runtime

Tags: html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-ui

I have been creating a form with lots of `<input type="checkbox">` for search and filter functionality. Please find the code below;

```
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="type" value="1" id="type1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="type1">Filter Sub Item</label>
   </div>
```

But when the page renders in the browser the DOM is appended with a new hidden field for each `<input type="checkbox">`

```
<input type="hidden" name="_type" value="on">
```

I am using Boostrap CSS library for the form design. How can I stop this from auto generating the hidden fields in the form.

When I submit the form with method="get" these hidden values are appearing in the browser address bar.

Comment: Well, I can show you the working example if you had a demo but generally you can make use of this event listener: [HTMLFormElement: submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

Comment: Yes, on submit we can remove all the hidden elements, but I don't want to `<input type="hidden" name="_type" value="on">` to be generated at all. Which library is causing this? @m4n0

Comment: Try removing libraries one at a time until you dont see those hidden fields. Start with `js` libraries first. Remove the basic ones like `jquery`, `popper` at the end

Comment: Tried removing the libraries but still it appears. Tried with different browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) but same.